# rangeOfCharacterFromSet returning unexpected results

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString* test = @"B";
BOOL wasFound = [test rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet capitalizedLetterCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound;
```

in this example wasFound is NO. I was wondering why. I'd like to be able to check if a one character string is a capital letter or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be mislead by the method name.

`capitilizedLetterCharacterSet` returns "titlecase" letters. `uppercaseLetterCharacterSet` ist probably what you are looking for.